Thingsboard - Assign all devices created by a gateway device to the owner of the gateway
Suppose the device A (with assigned customer) is a gateway device that creates devices B1 ... Bn (with relation created) by sending their first telemetries to the server. I want B1 ... Bn to be automatically assigned to customer.
A straightforward solution would be to add a "related attributes" enrichment node to the rule-chain, and I was hoping that it gets all the devices created by A, so I can assign them. But the docs says that  it will only give me one related device:

If multiple Related Entities are found, only first Entity is used for attributes enrichment, other entities are discarded.

I also found a way to do so by a "duplicate to related" node, but it is only available in Thingsboard PE, which I don't have.
The only solution that seems possible to me now is to use a "rest api call" node two times, first to fetch B1 ... Bn, and second to assign them.
Has anyone been in the same situation? Is there a better way to do it?
